# Django base.models.Post.DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I am very new to django. I have followed the steps from [a video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3hhLE1KR5Q) on how to create a simple blog. Basically, I have a portfolio main page that displays several things including the latest blogs. It all works well. I can see the latest posts on the main page. I can also click in each of them and they open up fine.

However, now, I want to create a new page (blog.html) that will hold all the posts. I created a blog.html and did the necessary settings in views.py and urls.py. However, for some reason I get an error when trying to access localhost/blog/

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('work/', views.work, name='work'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    ]
```

Here views.py:

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def blog(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: It means there is no `Post` with the given `slug`.

Comment: Hi Willem, the error seems to come from post_detail(), however, that page works flawlessly. There are no issues. The problem is that when I want to gather all the posts into blog.html I get this error.

Comment: Willem is right but you can also use the `get_object_or_404` in your view so that if no object is found it returns a 404 instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Comment: @user14903989: yes, but `blog` is a slug as well, and since you wrote `<slug:slug>/` *before* `blog/` it means it will trigger the `post_detail` view, not the `blog` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you trigger the `post_detail` view with a slug, and no `Post` with that slug exists. But here you simply trigger the *wrong* view. This is because `<slug:slug>/` will also match `blog/`, so you will *never* trigger the `blog/` view. You should *reorder* the views, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('work/', views.work, name='work'),
    # before <slug:slug>
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

It might however be better to make *non-overlapping* patterns, since now if you ever make a `Post` with `blog` as slug, that post is *inacessible*. You thus might want to rewrite the path to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('work/', views.work, name='work'),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    # non-overlapping patterns
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: That worked fine. It is also good to learn how the urls.py work! Many thanks